# What is the difference between uncertainly and uncertainty?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, differences

*Context: I was reading a book and came across the word “uncertainty” as I never saw this word before it makes me confuse.*

According to Dictionnary, the definition of **uncertainty** is:

> The state of being uncertain.

But the definition of **uncertainly** is as follows:

> With a lack of confidence or certainty.

So I really do not understand the difference between "Uncertainty" and "Uncertainly", both seem to express the fact of being not certain of something.

Comment: One is a noun, the other an adverb - which is something that any dictionary is bound to mention, and which is quite a difference in itself. The difference is similar to that between _greatness_ and _greatly_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a big difference between them.

According to Cambridge Dictionary:

"uncertainly" is an ADVERB which means not confidently or surely.

"uncertainty" is a NOUN means a situation in which something is not known or certain.

She looked at John uncertainly. Life is full of uncertainties.  I think that's a clear explanation.